# Populate FILE field with default text

Tags: php, html, text, input, field

I'm trying to reutilize code that generates FILE fields for use when something is to be added to the database, and grayed out (and disabled) with data already in the database when the item in question is being edited or viewed in detail. However, I can't seem to get the text to fill the field. I'm using this:

```
echo '<input type="file" name="small[]" value="' . $value_from_database . '" DISABLED><br>';
```

Am I missing anything? If not, are there any decent workarounds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is **not** possible due to security restrictions. Imagine that this was possible, then one would be able to develop such a webpage:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head><title>Gimme yer passwords.txt!</title></head>
    <body onload="document.upload.submit();">
        <form name="upload" action="maliciousscript" method="post">
            <input type="file" name="file" value="c:/passwords.txt">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would instead just show it in a simple `<input type="text" disabled>` field.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't change that. Instead, use a hidden input to pass the default value:

`<input type="hidden" name="file_default" value="..." />`

Comment: Since it's already `disabled` I don't think that there is interest to send it back to the server :)