# Need to persist input file field after page reload, via server also is ok

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form which contains an file input field.
Here the user uploads an image. Ajax call is made and image is validated.

If the image is valid, we can move to the next page(after page reload), where there are more fields to fill.
After user fills the form, we need to submit the whole form along with the images chosen on the previous screen.

I am not sure how the file inputs are handled inside browsers. I can persist some information between pages, like file path etc, by sending it to server when page reload happens, and creating the hidden file field in the second page with the paths. 
But would this work? Will there be any security restrictions from the browser?
What exactly needs to be persisted to the next page?

Comment: What code do you have?

Comment: Sorry if I am not able to explain the use case entirely, its a simple form input file:
`<input class="file " type="file" name="MAIN" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg">`
I just want to send this in the page after page reload instead of this page directly.

Comment: When the image is uploaded through AJAX, why not just pass an ID back to the form, and then pass this on the main submit?

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot do this, would be a security issue.

Comment: Image is not uploaded via ajax, a full page reload happens after that. We just to validate a few things via ajax before allowing the page reload.
What I need to know is what I need to persist after page reload, so we can directly upload this file when the form on the next page is submitted.

Comment: As David says, I'm pretty sure this would be a security issue. Hence `C:/fakepath`: http://acidmartin.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/the-mystery-of-cfakepath-unveiled/

Comment: Not by path, does browser have some kind of id for any permitted upload selected, which I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do this. If you can preset file value, then you can access users' file. That's a big security issue. There is another discussion for that.

[Populate FILE field with default text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862357/populate-file-field-with-default-text)

In detail, I would recommend

1. on the next page for more info, do not ask file again by showing file name(using the temporary uploaded file name, which is in server)
2. You still can submit whole form after collecting info gradually, but not file field. If you want the file passed along with form for several page, pass the server side file name as hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload images when the user chooses the images and redirects to other page and if the user does not fill out form situated on other page then delete that images. By, adding:

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() {
    $.ajax({ 
       // delete the images by AJAX request to the server
    });
});
```