# In codeigniter how to repopulate the form data for file input type

Tags: forms, file, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, the form input type=file is not re-population the data which is already selected after form validation failed for other fields.
How to do this.

And while editing the form for the type input type=file how to keep the value ok previous uploaded image and it the user not select the new image to upload then the form should not return false.

form

```
<tr>
                <td class="formrow"><span>Contact Person Email Id</span><span style="color:red;">*</span></td>      
                <td class="formrow1">
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $contact_person_email_id;?>" name="contact_person_email_id">
                    <span style="color:red;"><?php echo form_error('contact_person_email_id')?></span>
                </td>
                <td class="formrow">Company Logo<span style="color:red;">*</span></td>
                <td class="formrow1">
                <?php 
                if($id!=''){
                    ?>
                <img id="image" src="<?php echo base_url();?>uploads/<?php echo $company_logo;?>" width="150px" height="15px">
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                 <input type="file" value="<?php echo $company_logo;?>" name="company_logo" id="company_logo">
                    <span style="color:red;"><?php echo form_error('company_logo')?></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Are you redirecting from or loading a view from the controller after validation fail?

Comment: and for images update, I can suggest you something which I have applied.  For Updating any file or image you show them the file (in my case I have images) and put the file input field to update.

Comment: I'm loading a view after validation fail.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Populate FILE field with default text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862357/populate-file-field-with-default-text)

Comment: You can't do this for security reasons. Instead, you can create a list near to file input with saved files links.

Comment: @vijaykumar you should see this answer. May it helps You. To understand the scenario here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788308/fill-file-input-after-form-submit-on-form-submit-error

Answer (score 0):

Try this in value attribute:

```
$this->form_validation->set_value('element_name')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's a good solution or not, at least it works.

First, upload the image even if the validation fails, and save the name of an image in a session and print it beside the input to show to the user that the image is set.

Later, if the validation success, just processes the form and delete the session for the image.

Sometimes a user might change his/her mind and upload another image instead of the previous one, in this case, just remove the previous one by looking at the name from the session and save the new image's name in the session to override the name.

I tried this method and works for me. again not sure if this method of good.